# I am getting for type error in Scala

Tags: scala-collections

```
def getCandidateFrameByParentId(parentId: Int, pageNo: Int, pageSize: Int): Future[Pagination]= {
    candidateRepo.getCount(parentId).flatMap{
      count =>candidateRepo.getPage(parentId,pageNo,pageSize).map(frames =>
       frames.map{case (List(Candidate(frameId,phrase,id))) =>CandidatePhrases(id.get,phrase)
         Pagination(count,pageNo,pageSize,List(CandidatePhrases))
      })
    }
}
```

```
Error=>Type mismatch, expected: List[CandidatePhrases], actual: List[CandidatePhrases.type]

case class Pagination(count:Int,pageNo:Int,pageSize:Int,candidates:List[CandidatePhrases])

case class CandidatePhrases(id:Int,phrase:String)
```

Comment: Please post the code also and format your error message using the right markdown tab

Comment: I posted the code sir. please have a look into it.It is a service code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are not giving the proper arguments for the data constructor `CandidatePhrases`:

You should change

```
Pagination(count,pageNo,pageSize,List(CandidatePhrases))
```

to

```
Pagination(count,pageNo,pageSize,List(CandidatePhrases(args)))
```

where `args` are the arguments you want to pass to it.

The error is saying that you are creating a list which elements are data constructors, i.e., elements of type `CandidatePhrases.type`. Here's a tiny example of what you are doing:

```
scala> case class A(v: Int)
defined class A

scala> List(A)
res0: List[A.type] = List(A)

scala> List(A(1))
res1: List[A] = List(A(1))
```